# PhpStorm - How to change default zoom level

Tags: phpstorm, jetbrains-ide, phpstorm-2016.3

The default zoom level is way too high as you can see in the following screenshot, how can I change it?

[image: zoom]

I already searched the whole settings but found nothing.

Comment: What is that font you are using?

Comment: Im not sure, I think it is the default one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Editor font size can be changed in `Preferences | Editor | Colors&Fonts | Font` (don't forget to press `Save as` button to save the default schema as a custom one - predefined schemes can't be modified).
Note also that you can zoom the font in editor. To zoom text using keyboard, you need to assign preferred shortcuts to `Increase font size`, `Decrease font size` and `Reset font size` actions in `Preferences | Keymap | Editor Actions`; to do the same using mouse, enable `Change font size (Zoom) with Ctrl+Mouse Wheel` option in `Preferences | Editor | General` and use `Ctrl+mouse wheel` to zoom